# vectorise for loop with numpy.where

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
>>> b = np.array([1, 3, 4, 5])
>>> indices = np.zeros((len(a)))
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        indices[i] = np.where(b == a[i])[0][0]
    except:
        indices[i] = -1

>>> indices
array([ 0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
```

For each element of an `np.array`, how can I get its index in another `np.array` and also put a constant value (here, `-1`) where the element is not found in the latter one?

Comment: Are both `a` and `b` sorted?

Comment: `b` is sorted but `a` is not. From my understanding, the solution should still work, shouldn't it?

Comment: For my solution, I am using `np.searchsorted(b,a)`. So, I need `b` to be sorted. For Nils Werner's solution, he has `np.searchsorted(a, b)`, which needs `a` to be sorted.

Comment: yes, I meant yours, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to get the indices and then re-use those to get the invalid ones by comparing  the indexed ones against `a` and set those as `-1` -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(b,a)
idx[b[idx] != a] =-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.searchsorted()` and `np.in1d()`:

```
indices = np.searchsorted(b, a)
indices[~np.in1d(a, b)] = -1
print(indices)  # array([ 0,  0, -1,  1,  1,  2,  3])
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I swapped `a` and `b`. Fixed.